# How to wrap <h2> and <p> tags inside a <section> tag in xslt?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I want to wrap the headers and paragraph inside the section tags. Section tag ends when the next header arises.

Input:

```
<body>
    <h2>text text</h2>
    <p> some text </p>
    <p> some text </p>
    <h2> text text </h2>
    <p> some text </p>
    <p> some text </p>
    <p> some text </p>
</body>
```

Output:

```
 <body>
    <section>
        <h2>text text</h2>
        <p> some text </p>
        <p> some text </p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2> text text </h2>
        <p> some text </p>
        <p> some text </p>
        <p> some text </p>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: will you only every have `h2` and `p` tags, or will there be others (such as `h3` or "section" content other than `p`) that you have to deal with as well?

Comment: yes, there can be others tags below the h2 tags. but section must start above h2 tags and end before next h2 tag

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. Anyway, do a search - it's probably the most often asked question here.

Comment: The `for-each-group group-starting-with` example in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples should give you an idea if you can use an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments, this is a grouping question.

If you're using XSLT 2.0, you can use `xsl:for-each-group/@group-starting-with`...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h2">
        <section>
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </section>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you're stuck with XSLT 1.0, you can use an `xsl:key` based on a generated id of the `h2`...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="sectElems" match="/body/*[not(self::h2)]" 
    use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::h2[1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="/body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="h2"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h2">
    <xsl:variable name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <section>
      <xsl:copy-of select=".|key('sectElems',$id)"/>
    </section>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Both of these stylesheets produce the same output.